# map<const char*,...> не индексируется через char[]

Tags: c++, map

должно выводить 10, но выводит 0

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <map>

map<const char*,int>m;

int main()
{
    char text[]="test";
    
    m.emplace((const char*)text,10);
    cout<<m["test"];
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сравнение идёт не по строке, а по указателю. Используйте `std::string`.

Comment: не хочу string, я там узнал что есть компаратор третьим шаблоном, но остался вопрос есть ли готовый компаратор для const char*?

Answer (score 1):

Готового нет, но его [несложно и написать](https://ideone.com/O2a5Rp)...

```
auto comp = [](const char* a, const char*b){ return strcmp(a,b) < 0; };
map<const char*,int,decltype(comp)> m{ comp };

int main()
{
    char text[]="test";
    
    m.emplace((const char*)text,10);
    cout<<m["test"];
    
    return 0;
}
```

Только учтите, что раз в `map` вносится только *указатель*, то он должен быть действителен, пока существует ваш `map`...

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: код не работает

    6 | map<const char*,int,decltype(comp)> m{ comp };
      | ^~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:5: error: ‘m’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘tm’?
   12 |     m.emplace((const char*)text,10);
      |     ^
      |     tm

Comment: @LuaКолдун Посмотрите по указанной в ответе ссылке — https://ideone.com/O2a5Rp — как видите, все компилируется и работает... Может, вы где-то что-то не так набрали?

Answer (score 0):

Вы устанавливаете в map пару,  с ключом указатель. Напишем  ваш код подробно.

```
//нет необходдимости явного приведения, но все же
const char* temp1 = (const char*)text;     
m.emplace(temp1, 10);
```

То есть вы намеренно создаете указатель, и он является  ключом при установке,  а при поиске _ другой указатель, и не важно что массивы строк одинаковы. Точно так же, если вы установите указатель на временный массив, то  указатель `text` не будет ключом  этого элемента.

```
m.emplace("test", 10);   
cout << m[text]; //добавлен новый элемент
```

Ищите то,  что установлено:

```
m.emplace(text, 10);   
cout << m[text];
```

или

```
m.emplace("test", 10);   
cout << m["test"];
```

Comment: а как сделать чтобы ключом был текст, а не указатель?

Comment: На этот вопрос  ответили Harry и maestro